# Canadian visa agencies like canadianvisaexpert - are the legit or should I fill out the visa forms myself?

Tags: visas, canada

I plan traveling to Canada in order to visit my brother (and his family) and to travel around for 3 weeks in Canada. I know that I can fill all the visa forms online, but a friend told me that if I will make a mistake, or somehow miss something my visa application will be rejected and I will not be able to apply again.

so I have 2 options either to use the service of a lawyer or the services on an agency like canadianvisaexpert.

I now that in the end of the day a lawyer as well as canadianvisaexpert just fill up forms for me, but as this is their job, they probably will not do any mistakes.
saying that are agencies like canadianvisaexpert are legit service provider that can actually do what they say or should I use a lawyer?

Comment: i think that the biggest issue here that people dont understand they buy a visa application service not the visa itself

Comment: @Henning found it on the thread you posted. looks like the biggest scam is Scambook.com Itself :) :)  http://www.nbcchicago.com/video/#!/investigations/series/target-5/Is-Scambook-com-a-Scam-Itself-/170291966

Comment: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/index.asp
Have fun

Answer (score 4):

if it is so important for you, use a lawyer. They must be committed to you as a client. Much more than an agency

look what they say here

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/representative/rep-who.asp

**Paid representatives**

Only some people can charge a fee or receive any other type of payment to represent or advise you on a Canadian immigration or citizenship proceeding or application. These are:

```
lawyers and paralegals who are members in good standing of a Canadian provincial or territorial law society,
notaries who are members in good standing of the Chamber des notaries du Québec and
citizenship or immigration consultants who are members in good standing of the Immigration Consultants of Canada Regulatory Council.
```

These people are called “authorized” representatives.

CIC will not deal with representatives who charge for their services and are not members of one of the above groups.
Other people who offer paid immigration or citizenship advice

Anyone who gives you paid advice before you apply or start a proceeding must be authorized. Unauthorized people must either become authorized or refer you to someone who is.

**If you pay a representative, they must be authorized if they:**

```
act on your behalf during an immigration or citizenship proceeding by speaking for you,
help you choose the best immigration stream or
fill out any forms.
```

Answer (score 3):

From some googling (and memory from when I applied for a Canadian WHP visa), they're real, but they have a LOT of complaints.  [Scambook's page on them](http://www.scambook.com/company/view/98638/Canadian-Visa-Expert):

> Information about Canadian Visa Expert was first submitted to Scambook
>   on Dec 09, 2012. Since then the page has accumulated 157 consumer
>   complaints. On average users reported $1647.53 of damages. Scambook's
>   investigation team reached out to this company a total of 2 times,
>   Scambook Investigators last contacted them on Feb 05, 2013

They also receive a B- on the [BBB](http://www.bbb.org/kitchener/business-reviews/immigration-and-naturalization-consultants/canadian-visa-expert-in-markham-on-1297897), having had a few complaints registered there, with at least one resulting in a full refund.

Read into that what you will.

To be honest, I did the process myself.  The first time I did it I made a mistake, left out something blindingly obvious, and they just sent it back immediately - not rejected, just with a note to add the extra item.  So it doesn't mean you can't apply again - I certainly did.

Comment: according to NBC apparently  **Scambook is a scam** itself. **Scambook demanding money from businesses**  :) http://www.nbcchicago.com/video/#!/investigations/series/target-5/Is-Scambook-com-a-Scam-Itself-/170291966 . its like the "Yelp Scandal" http://www.natlawreview.com/article/yelp-scandal-red-flag-online-reviews

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know how you got to canadianvisaexpert but have a look on this from C.I.C
http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/media/notices/notice-fraud.asp

What you need to know:

You do not need to hire an immigration representative to apply for a visa or for Canadian citizenship.
    Immigration representatives do not have special connections with Canadian government officials and cannot guarantee you a visa.
    Only authorized officers at Canadian embassies, high commissions and consulates can decide whether or not to issue a visa.
    Don’t be tempted into using false documents as this will result in the refusal of your application.
    Beware of internet scams and false websites. The official website of Citizenship and Immigration Canada (CIC) is www.cic.gc.ca.
    You will find free application forms and guides for any type of visa on CIC’s website.
    Processing fees are the same at all Canadian visa offices around the world. Fees in local currency are based on official exchange rates and correspond with the amount in Canadian dollars.
    Canadian visa offices will never ask you to deposit money into an individual’s personal bank accounts or to transfer money through a specific private money transfer company.
    If you have questions, contact CIC or the visa office responsible for your area.

To read more, including information on who can legally represent you if you choose to hire an immigration representative, check out CIC’s web pages on Immigration Representatives.

Comment: its a service, exactly like submitting your yearly tax report to the IRS in the US. If you know what you do, it is better do it by yourself, if not, its better to pay a professional to do it for you.